# linq to sql query not performing

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, asp.net-4.0

I have Linq to Sql on my .NET 4.0 Console Application, and I've tested the queries and some work fine, though when I try to perform this specific query on debug mode, it just gets stuck on it and work continue (it just wont do anything).

```
List<Data.OWNER> activeOwnersForNet1 =
            (from loadd in OrderITDataContext.RECIPE_LOAD_DATAs
             join owner in OrderITDataContext.OWNERs on loadd.RCPLOADD_OWNER equals owner.OWN_ID
             where loadd.RCPLOADD_STATUS == 100 &&
                     owner.OWN_NET_ID == 1
             select owner).ToList();
```

Notice that even without the where clauses it wont work. The tables are connected on SQL database also (FK relationship).
What could be the reason for this strange behavior?

Comment: If you were to write the same query in SQL (with and without the WHERE clause), how long does it take to run?

Comment: How many records do you have in each of the tables? Do you have indexes on the columns you use for the join and where clauses?

Comment: Use Log to display the query and then look at the query plan in SSMS.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386961.aspx  And accept more answers

Comment: You are correct, I have a stupid mistake on the query itself.
By accepting more answers you mean on questions I've previously asked, right?

Comment: Correct. People tend to give more/better answers the more you accept them.

Answer (score 0):

Use Log to display the query and then look at the query plan in SSMS.

[How to: Display Generated SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386961.aspx)